# Opening a folder with files and transferring the names to a list box. Double clicking then transfers to textbox

Tags: c#

I have a select folder function here that looks for .txt files and .lua files in the user's selected folder, it takes the **names** of those files, and puts them in a list box.

```
    private void selectFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
                string[] txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.txt");
                string[] luafiles = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.lua");
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("OK! Here are the number of ususable files i've found. TxtFiles: " + txtfiles.Length.ToString() + " LuaFiles: " + luafiles.Length.ToString() + "");                    
                var wqert = Directory.EnumerateFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".txt") || s.EndsWith(".lua"));                    
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++);
                {

                    foreach (var luafile in luafiles)
                    {
                        File.ReadAllText(luafile.ToString());                            
                        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(luafile.ToString()));
                    }
                    foreach (var txtfile in txtfiles)
                    {
                        File.ReadAllText(txtfile.ToString());
                        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(txtfile.ToString()));

                    }


                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I wish to make an event where when I double-click one of the items on the list box, it takes whatever "stuff" that is inside the files and puts it into a richtextbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely a number of ways in which you can complete this, I tend to use this method:

First, Create a class to hold the filename and its content

```
public class FileObject
{
    public String FileName { get; set; }
    public String FileContent { get; set; }
}
```

Second, when you loop through the file names, you will need to create a new instance of the `FileObject` class and set its properties:

```
foreach (var luafile in luafiles)
{
    FileObject f = new FileObject();
    f.FileName = Path.GetFileName(luafile.ToString());
    f.Content = File.ReadAllText(luafile.ToString());                            
    listBox1.Items.Add(f);
}

foreach (var txtfile in txtfiles)
{
    FileObject f = new FileObject();
    f.FileName = Path.GetFileName(txtfile.ToString());
    f.Content = File.ReadAllText(txtfile.ToString());                            
    listBox1.Items.Add(f);
}
```

Third, as you are now populating the `ListBox` control with objects instead of strings it will be necessary to set its DataBinding properties:

```
listBox1.ValueMember = "FileName";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName";
```

Finally, you will need to handle the ListBox DoubleClick event in order to carry out your desired action of populating the RichTextBox

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileObject fileObject = (FileObject)listBox1.SelectedItem;

    // Populate the RichTextBox here - I output to the Console as a demo
    Console.WriteLine(fileObject.FileContent);
}
```

Note: If there are a lot of files and/or large content then this method will consume a lot of memory as each file will be loaded in to memory and hang around

Comment: @DevanshTayal Great to hear it works for you, don't forget to accept it as the answer to help others with the same problem find an answer

Comment: just to be clear, where do I put the value member and display member for the listbox?

Comment: `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` are properties of the `ListBox` control. They can be set in either the Designer or in code. If you do it i code, it must be after the call to `InitializeComponent`